# Why did the Rebel Alliance change their mind and support the attack on Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

The one guy ran in yelling at Mon Mothma and then they almost all send their fighter support. What exactly happened?

Answer (score 8):

The person who ran in told her that the Rebels had made it to Scarif:

> “Intercepted Imperial transmission, ma’am,” the private answered.
> “Rebels on Scarif.”
>
> Scarif? How was that possible?
>
> But the answer was obvious. She saw it on Draven’s face, too, and
> Merrick’s. While Mon had spent the night clutching like a miser at
> whatever pieces of the Alliance she might preserve, Jyn Erso had gone
> to risk everything she had.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

**First, the fact that such a small Rebel team had made it as far as the surface of Scarif might have motivated others to see the mission as less hopeless.** But more than that, it seems that many people (such as Raddus) had already gone:

> She fixed the private with a sober look. “I need to speak to Admiral
> Raddus,” she said.
>
> “He’s left already.” The man was almost stammering. “He’s in orbit
> aboard the Profundity. He’s gone to fight.”
>
> “I see,” she said, and slowly smiled. Merrick’s expression was
> expectant; Draven’s grave and resolved.
>
> **Perhaps she had given up hope too swiftly.**
>
> Less than ten minutes later, sirens were announcing the departure of
> Red, Blue, Green, and Gold Squadrons along with the U-wing transports.
> Raddus had already contacted all capital ships within range of Yavin
> or Scarif. Draven had brusquely warned Mon not to think of joining the
> mission, no matter how inspirational she thought she might be; but the
> warning hadn’t been necessary. Mon understood her limits too well to
> get in the way.
>
> Instead she reminded herself of her pride in the soldiers of the
> Alliance and watched pilots and infantry personnel and technicians
> scramble to their vessels. Anyone capable of contributing would find
> his or her abilities welcome in the coming battle.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

Thus Mothma was only bowing to the decision that many of the military commanders  of the Alliance had already made.

Answer (score 1):

Mon Mothma and her close advisers were extremely keen to attack Scarif. The Rebel Council (comprising senators and fleet commanders from a dozen different sectors) were less keen. They took a vote and Mothma ultimately lost.

When she discovered that Jyn Erso was already on the planet (having "*gone rogue*") she asked to speak to Raddus only to discover that **he'd also left for Scarif, along with the pride of the Rebel Fleet, the Profundity.**

> **Mon Mothma:** *I need to Speak to Admiral Raddus*
>
> **Private:** *He's returned to his ship. He's going to fight!*

Since the plan was already underway, and with the Council absent, Mon Mothma decided to accept the [*fait accompli*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fait-accompli) and order the ships that remained in orbit to support the insertion team.

> *Draven and Merrick glanced at Mon Mothma then, and she had to do her
> best to suppress a smile. **She was pleased that Jyn and Cassian had
> gone to Scarif to complete the mission the high command didn’t have
> the stomach to back. Now Raddus might also make sure they got the help
> they deserved.***
>
> *The two generals scrambled off to see what they could do about it, but
> Mothma knew they were already too late. **There would still be ships
> hurrying to catch up with Raddus in orbit, but none of them would
> refuse the admiral’s orders to join him in jumping to Scarif.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>